# 2D inhomogeneous biharmonic equation

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, finite-element-method

How to solve a 2D inhomogeneous [biharmonic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biharmonic_equation) with `NDSolve`?

I tried the following code:

```
P[x_, y_] := x y
eq = Laplacian[Laplacian[w[x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] == x*y;
bc = {w[0, y] == w[1, y] == w[x, 0] == w[x, 1] == 0, 
Derivative[2, 0][w][0, y] == Derivative[2, 0][w][1, y] == 
Derivative[0, 2][w][x, 0] == Derivative[0, 2][w][x, 1] == 0};
NDSolve[{eq == P[x, y], bc}, w, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

but it says

> NDSolve::femcmsd: The spatial derivative order of the PDE
>   may not exceed two.

How to derive the solution?

Comment: As the error message says, `NDSolve` is not able to solve this problem as written.  However, you could Fourier transform the system in one or both dimensions and proceed from there.

Comment: What are `bc` and `P[x,y]`?

Comment: MMM, bcs are w[0,y]=w[1,y]=w[x,0]=w[x,1]=0 and (D[w[x,y],x,x]/.x->0)=(D[w[x,y],x,x]/.x->1)=(D[w[x,y],y,y]/.y->0)=(D[w[x,y],y,y]/.y->1)=0 and $P[x,y]=x*y$, for example.

Comment: bbgodfrey, actually, the governing equation is nonlinear, so Fourier or other similar things are useful.

Comment: You should add the b.c.s and `P` to your question by clicking the [edit](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/posts/135893/edit) button.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic Euler–Bernoulli beam equation](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/127980/dynamic-euler-bernoulli-beam-equation)

Comment: @user21 I think that post is closer to a related one?

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this question because the 4 votes asking for additional information is actually voted before OP adds specific code i.e. additional information. (Notice the decisive vote by @user21 is suggesting a possible duplicate. )

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As mentioned in the warning, currently `"FiniteElement"` method can't handle 4th order spatial derivatives. So let me show you a FDM-based solution. I'll use [`pdetoae`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127997/1871) for the generation of difference equation:

```
P[x_, y_] := x y
eq = Laplacian[Laplacian[w[x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] == P[x, y];
bc = {w[0, y] == w[1, y] == w[x, 0] == w[x, 1] == 0, 
    Derivative[2, 0][w][0, y] == Derivative[2, 0][w][1, y] == 
     Derivative[0, 2][w][x, 0] == Derivative[0, 2][w][x, 1] == 0} /. 
   Equal[a__, b_] :> Thread[{a} == b];
{bcy, bcx} = GatherBy[Flatten@bc, FreeQ[#, _[0 | 1, y]] &];
domain = {0, 1};
points = 25;
grid = Array[# &, points, domain];
difforder = 4;
(*Definition of pdetoae isn't included in this code piece,
  please find it in the link above.*)
ptoafunc = pdetoae[w[x, y], {grid, grid}, difforder];
var = Outer[w, grid, grid] // Flatten;

del = #[[3 ;; -3]] &;

ae = del /@ del@ptoafunc@eq;
aebcx = ptoafunc@bcx;
aebcy = del /@ ptoafunc@bcy;

{b, m} = CoefficientArrays[{ae, aebcx, aebcy} // Flatten, var];

sollst = LinearSolve[m, -N@b];
```

> **Remark**
>
> If you have difficulty in understanding the usage of `del`, the
>   following is an alternative way for calculating `sollst`:
>
> ```
> fullsys = ptoafunc@{eq, bcx, bcy} // Flatten;
> {b, m} = CoefficientArrays[fullsys, var];
> sollst = LeastSquares[m, -N@b]; // AbsoluteTiming
> ```
>
> Notice this approach is slower.

```
sol = ListInterpolation[Partition[sollst, points], {grid, grid}];

Plot3D[sol[x, y], {x, ##}, {y, ##}] & @@ domain
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Notice I've modified the definition of `bc` because `pdetoae` can't parse continued equality at the moment i.e. something like `a == b == c` isn't supported yet.

---

**Solution for the problem in the comments below**

The new-added example in the comment has a nonlinear inhomogeneous term, so `LinearSolve` can't be used any more, we can use `FindRoot` instead:

```
nu = 0.33; h = 0.01; Ye = 2 10^11; P1 = 10^5; 
N11[x_, y_] = (Ye h)/(2 (1 - nu^2)) ((D[w[x, y], x])^2 + nu (D[w[x, y], y])^2);
 N22[x_, y_] = (Ye h)/(2 (1 - nu^2)) (nu (D[w[x, y], x])^2 + (D[w[x, y], y])^2);
 N12[x_, y_] = (Ye h)/(2 (1 + nu)) D[w[x, y], x] D[w[x, y], y] ;
P[x_, y_] = 
  N11[x, y] D[w[x, y], x, x] - N22[x, y] D[w[x, y], y, y] - 
   2 N12[x, y] D[w[x, y], x, y] - P1;
eq = (Ye h^3)/(12 (1 - nu^2)) Laplacian[Laplacian[w[x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] == -P[x, 
    y]; bc = {w[x, 0] == w[x, 1] == 0, 
   Derivative[2, 0][w][0, y] == Derivative[2, 0][w][1, y] == 0, 
   Derivative[0, 2][w][x, 0] == Derivative[0, 2][w][x, 1] == 
    0, (Ye h^3)/(12 (1 - nu^2)) (Derivative[3, 0][w][0, y] + 
        2 Derivative[1, 2][w][0, y]) + P1 Derivative[1, 0][w][0, y] == 
    0, (Ye h^3)/(12 (1 - nu^2)) (Derivative[3, 0][w][1, y] + 
        2 Derivative[1, 2][w][1, y]) + P1 Derivative[1, 0][w][1, y] == 0} /. 
  Equal[a__, b_] :> Thread[{a} == b];   
{bcy, bcx} = GatherBy[Flatten@bc, FreeQ[#, _[0 | 1, y]] &];
domain = {0, 1};
points = 25;
grid = Array[# &, points, domain];
difforder = 4;
(* Definition of pdetoae isn't included in this code piece,
  please find it in the link above. *)
ptoafunc = pdetoae[w[x, y], {grid, grid}, difforder];    
del = #[[3 ;; -3]] &;    
ae = del /@ del@ptoafunc@eq;
aebcx = ptoafunc@bcx;
aebcy = del /@ ptoafunc@bcy;    
var = Outer[w, grid, grid] // Flatten;

solrule = FindRoot[Rationalize[{ae, aebcx, aebcy} // Flatten, 0], {#, 0} & /@ var, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 16]; // AbsoluteTiming
sollst = Replace[solrule, (w[x_, y_] -> z_) :> {x, y, z}, {1}];
sol = Interpolation@sollst;   
Plot3D[sol[x, y], {x, ##}, {y, ##}] & @@ domain
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Notice setting proper initial values for `FindRoot` can be troublesome, but luckily it seems not to be a big problem in this case.

Comment: Actually, the deflection should be downwards. However, when I want to apply the code for the following set:

Comment: nu = 0.33; h = 0.01;  Ye = 2 10^11; P1 = 10^5;
N11[x_, y_] := (Ye h)/(
  2 (1 - nu^2)) ((D[w[x, y], x])^2 + nu (D[w[x, y], y])^2)
N22[x_, y_] := (Ye h)/(
  2 (1 - nu^2)) (nu (D[w[x, y], x])^2 + (D[w[x, y], y])^2)
N12[x_, y_] := (Ye h)/(2 (1 + nu)) D[w[x, y], x] D[w[x, y], y]
P[x_, y_] := 
 N11[x, y] D[w[x, y], x, x] - N22[x, y] D[w[x, y], y, y] - 
  2 N12[x, y] D[w[x, y], x, y] - P1

Comment: eq = (Ye h^3)/(12 (1 - nu^2))
     Laplacian[Laplacian[w[x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] == -P[x, y];
bc = {w[x, 0] == w[x, 1] == 0, 
    Derivative[2, 0][w][0, y] == Derivative[2, 0][w][1, y] == 0 == 
     Derivative[0, 2][w][x, 0] == Derivative[0, 2][w][x, 1] == 
     0, (Ye h^3)/(
       12 (1 - nu^2)) (Derivative[3, 0][w][0, y] + 
         2 Derivative[1, 2][w][0, y]) + 
      P1 Derivative[1, 0][w][0, y] == 
     0, (Ye h^3)/(
       12 (1 - nu^2)) (Derivative[3, 0][w][1, y] + 
         2 Derivative[1, 2][w][1, y]) + 
      P1 Derivative[1, 0][w][1, y] == 0}

Comment: It doesn`t work.

Comment: @AsaturKhurshudyan Check my edit.

Comment: Thanks, it is physically correct. Thank you very much.

Comment: To the downvoter, I am interested in what's wrong with my answer, would you please elaborate. I'm not trying to complain here, I just want to improve my answer if possible.

Comment: your answer solved my problem and, in fact, I am still using your code. So, there shouldn't be anything to be improved.

Comment: @xzczd can we use FDM-based solution for 2D/3D solid mechanic problems in MMA? If Yes, I will give a try in MMA!

Comment: @ABCDEMMM As long as the region is regular. (Rectangle, ball, etc. ) Somewhat related: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/10187/5331

Comment: @xzczd  thanks a lot for your support!

Answer (score 15):

**Update:**

The example has been added to the help system. You can find it by clicking on the message NDSolve::femcmsd and following the link or by going to FEMDocumentation/ref/message/InitializePDECoefficients/femcmsd

---

For completeness I'd like to show that you can use the FEM to solve the biharmonic equation. The trick is to rewrite the 4th order equation as a system of two second order equations like so:

```
P[x_, y_] := x y
eqn = {Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] == v[x, y],
   Laplacian[v[x, y], {x, y}] == P[x, y]};
bcs = {u[0, y] == u[1, y] == u[x, 0] == u[x, 1] == 0, 
   v[0, y] == v[1, y] == v[x, 0] == v[x, 1] == 0};
ufun = NDSolveValue[{eqn, bcs}, u, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
(* alternative workaround for version 13.0.1 *)
(* ufun = NDSolveValue[{eqn, bcs}, {u, v}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}][[1]] *)
```

Note that the derivative boundary conditions from the original problem now are dirichlet conditions for the system of the equations.

A plot and a comparison to the other solutions show that is works well:

```
Plot3D[ufun[x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Compare this answer (`ufun`) to the answer given in xzczd's post (`sol`) to show that they match up.

```
Plot3D[ufun[x, y] - sol[x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Really nice and simpler.

Comment: What is here `sol[x,y]`?

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch, the solution from the other answer. To sow that the answers match up. I'll edit the post to make that clearer.

Comment: @use21   can we solve 4th order problems using Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines", "SpatialDiscretization" -> "TensorProductGrid"}}?

Comment: @ABCDEMMM, time dependent yes, stationary like this one, no.

Comment: @user21  thanks! If I want to solve a 4th order One-Dimensional problems, is it possible direct using NDSolve ?

Comment: @ABCDEMMM, depending on the problem, depending on the definition of 'direct', yes.

Comment: @user21  is it that NSolve can only solve second order ode problems? example, plate or beam?

Comment: @ABCDEMMM, I assume you mean `NDSolve` not `NSolve`. Yes, `NDSolve` can solve other then second order problems. The documentation has many examples. I do not understand what you want to know with: 'example, plate or beam ?'

Comment: @ABCDEMMM, do you mean [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/127980/18437)

Comment: @user21   yes, I am thinking, can we use mixed formulation for this problem, two two second gradient fields.

Comment: @ABCDEMMM, unfortunately I do not understand what you are asking.

Comment: @user21 I cannot seem to run the first block of code in the answer to solve for u[x,y] in Mathematica 13.0.1, as in it does not evaluate to solve for u. Has something changed ?

Comment: @Charlie, try to solve for u and v and not only for u.

Comment: @user21 I gave NDSolve the arguments {u,v} in sol = NDSolveValue[{eqn, bcs}, {u,v}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}] and it does give a solution but then ufun does not match sol[[1]]

Comment: @Charlie, works just fine for me.