# Solving a biharmonic eigenvalue Problem

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, eigenvalues

I am interested in solving the following biharmonic **eigenvalue problem**.

$$\begin{array}{cccc}
  & \Delta ^2  \Psi (x,y) = \lambda \Psi (x,y), & - \frac{\pi}{2} \le x \le \frac{\pi}{2} &  -\frac{\pi}{2} \le y \le \frac{\pi}{2} \\
  & x = \phantom{-}\frac{\pi}{2} & \Psi = 0 &   \dfrac{\partial \Psi }{\partial x} = 0 \\
  & x =  - \frac{\pi}{2} & \Psi = 0 &  \dfrac{\partial  \Psi }{\partial x} = 0 \\
  & y = \phantom{-}\frac{\pi}{2} & \Psi = 0 &  \dfrac{\partial  \Psi }{ \partial y} = 0 \\
 & y =  - \frac{\pi}{2} & \Psi = 0 &  \dfrac{\partial  \Psi }{ \partial y} = 0 
\end{array}
$$

where $\Delta^2$ is the biharmonic operator.

$$ \Delta ^2 \Psi  = \frac{\partial ^4 \Psi }{\partial x^4} + 2 \frac{\partial^4 \Psi }{\partial x^2 \partial y^2} + \frac{\partial ^4 \Psi }{\partial y^4}$$

I looked into `DEigenvalues` but I couldn't understand how the BCs are determined.

> Can anyone help me to tell *Mathematica* to find the first five eigenvalues of this problem for me? I am interested to use finite elements.

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/135893/2d-inhomogeneous-biharmonic-equation

Comment: @user21: Can I ask that why you closed this question? This is an eigen-value problem while in the linked question you addressed to solve an inhomogeneous biharmonic BVP.

Comment: My understanding is that your question is the same as the one referenced. Why don't you update your question with an explanation of why the linked answer is not applicable to your question? If that is the case then we can reopen your question, I'd say.

Comment: Is the applicability of the coupled PDE that represents the biharmonic equation to `NDEigenstem` the problem?

Comment: I see there might be some issue in applying the result from the linked question to `NDEigenstem` but it would be good to point out that that issue actually is?

Comment: "I am interested to use finite elements." So, answer using other methods will be off-topic under this question, right?

Comment: @xzczd: If you have some innovative approach in mind, you are welcomed to present it here. :)

Answer (score 9):

> If you have some innovative approach in mind…

Hmm… I have a solution based on finite difference method (FDM), which is said to be the earliest numeric method for PDE solving. Anyway, it might be viewed as innovative in the sence that it shows FEM isn't the only possible numeric approach, so let me post it here.

### FDM Based Solution

I've used [`pdetoae`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127997/1871) for the generation of difference equations.

```
lap = Laplacian[#, {x, y}] &;
domain = {-Pi/2, Pi/2};
togeneralpattern = (a_ -> b_) :> Quiet@((a /. v : x | y -> v_) -> b);
With[{u = u[x, y]}, lhs = lap@lap@u;]

points = 400;
grid = Array[# &, points, domain];
difforder = 4;
ptoafunc = pdetoae[u[x, y], {grid, grid}, difforder];
discretelhs = ptoafunc@lhs;

ptoafuncmid = pdetoae[mid[x], grid, difforder];       
eqmid = mid'[#] == 0 & /@ domain // ptoafuncmid
varmid = mid /@ grid[[{2, -2}]]
rulemid = Flatten@MapThread[Solve, {eqmid, varmid}]
rulebc1 = Flatten@Table[rulemid, {mid, {u[x, #] &, u[#, y] &}}] /. togeneralpattern

del = #[[3 ;; -3, 3 ;; -3]] &;
innerlhs = Flatten@del@discretelhs;
innervar = Flatten@del@Table[u[x, y], {x, grid}, {y, grid}];
Block[{u}, Set @@@ rulebc1;
   {barray, marray} = CoefficientArrays[innerlhs, innervar]]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {38.2806, Null} *)

{val, vec} = Eigensystem[marray // N, -10]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {21.8352, Null} *)

mat = Partition[#, points - 4] & /@ vec;
val
(* {454.983, 454.983, 279.493, 279.493, 179.43, 
    177.74,  120.223, 55.2993, 55.2993, 13.2938} *)

ArrayPlot[#, ColorFunction -> "AvocadoColors"] & /@ mat
```

[image]

You may further adjust `points` and `difforder` to check if the result is reliable.

**Remark**

The Dirichlet b.c.s are essentially set by `del`, to be precise, by removing outermost elements of `Table[u[x, y], {x, grid}, {y, grid}]`.

---

### Update: Pseudospectral Method Based Solution

If you've read some of my answers using `pdetoae`, you may have noticed I've directly substitute the Neumann b.c.s into the system with the `Set @@@ rulebc1;` here, which is an approach I seldom took to impose b.c., because it makes the coding more involved. Nevertheless, if I replace part of discretized PDEs with b.c.s as I've usually done, we'll have to calculate generalized eigenvalues AFAIK, and the underlying algorithm of `Eigensystem` for generalized eigenvalues seems to be much less efficient.

It's better to illustrate with an example. In the following solution, pseudospectral method, for which direct substitution of b.c.s doesn't work well because the expressions of discretized system are so large in this case, is implemented.

```
lap = Laplacian[#, {x, y}] &;
domain = {-Pi/2, Pi/2};
With[{u = u[x, y]}, eq = {lap@lap@u, u};
  {bcx, bcy} = Table[{{u, ϵ u}, {D[u, var], ϵ u}} /. 
     var -> boundary, {var, {x, y}}, {boundary, domain}]];

Off[NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative::ordred]
points = 35;
CGLGrid[{xl_, xr_}, n_] := 1/2 (xl + xr + (xl - xr) Cos[(π Range[0, n - 1])/(n - 1)]);
grid = N@CGLGrid[domain, points];
difforder = points;
ptoafunc = pdetoae[u[x, y], {grid, grid}, difforder];
del = #[[3 ;; -3]] &;
discreteeq = del /@ del@# & /@ ptoafunc@eq;
discretebcx = Map[del, ptoafunc@bcx, {3}];
discretebcy = ptoafunc@bcy;
discretesys = 
  Flatten@{discreteeq[[#]], discretebcx[[All, All, #]], discretebcy[[All, All, #]]} &;
var = Table[u[x, y], {x, grid}, {y, grid}] // Flatten;
{barray, marray} = CoefficientArrays[discretesys@1, var]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {2.33509, Null} *)
{barray2, aarray} = CoefficientArrays[discretesys@2 /. ϵ -> 0., var]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.0019331, Null} *)
{val, vec} = Eigensystem[{marray, aarray} // N, -10]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {11.0801, Null} *)
MaxMemoryUsed[]/1024^3. GB
(* 0.581552 GB *)
val
(*
{454.983 + 0. I, 454.983 + 0. I, 279.493 + 0. I, 279.493 + 0. I, 179.43 + 0. I, 
 177.74 + 0. I,  120.223 + 0. I, 55.2993 + 0. I, 55.2993 + 0. I, 13.2938 + 0. I}
 *)
```

As we can see, with only `35` grid points, we obtain a solution that's almost the same as that obtained with 4th order difference scheme and `400` grid points, which shows the power of pseudospectral method. However, just increase `points` a little to, say, `50`, you'll see the timing of `Eigensystem` increase to `114.809` and memory usage to `2.61183 GB`, while with the method in first section, the timing is `0.13103 s` and memory usage `0.153116 GB`. Changing `difforder` to `4` doesn't help. The efficiency of generalized eigenvalue calculation is a bottleneck here.

BTW, to visualize the eigenfunction, we can't simply use `ArrayPlot` in this case, because the grid is no longer uniform. Interpolation is necessary:

```
mat = Partition[#, points] & /@ vec;
func = ListInterpolation[#, {grid, grid}] & /@ mat;

(f \[Function] 
   DensityPlot[f[x, y], {x, ##}, {y, ##}, PlotPoints -> points, 
      ColorFunction -> "AvocadoColors"] & @@ domain) /@ func
```

Comment: (+1), Thanks for the nice and comprehensive answer. :)

Comment: @HoseinRahnama There's a mistake in my original implementation and now it's corrected. It's somewhat surprising the mistake doesn't influence the result that much, which seems to be consistent with the observation [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/163486/1871).

Comment: @xzczd why not use the spectral method?

Comment: @ABCDEMMM If you mean Pseudospectral, with the technique mentioned in the comments [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/204883/1871) it can be used, but I'm afraid it's not the best choice in this case. I've added an implementation of pseudospectral method to my answer , you may play with it.

Comment: @xzczd 我想知道回答中的图形是哪个具体的调和方程的数值解，能否给出具体的方程和边界条件。

Comment: @PleaseCorrectGrammarMistakes ……请仔细阅读问题。

Comment: @xzczd  why  Pseudospectral method much slower than FDM in MMA is? Hard to understand...

Comment: @ABCDEMMM As mentioned in the answer, underlying algorithm of `Eigensystem` for **generalized eigenvalues** (notice I'm utilizing a different syntax of `Eigensystem` in 2nd section) is a bottleneck. And, even if we turn back to the method in 1st section (notice the generation of `marray` will be slow in this case: about 20 seconds for `points=35` on my laptop), the calculation of eigenvalue will still be much slower, because `marray` for pseudospectral method is not sparse.

Answer (score 3):

You could start with something like this:

```
eqn = {Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] - v[x, y], 
   Laplacian[v[x, y], {x, y}]};
bcs = DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, True];
ufun = NDEigenvalues[{eqn, bcs}, {u, v}, {x, -Pi/2, Pi/2}, {y, -Pi/2, 
   Pi/2}, 5]
```

This will give a warning message about a possible non positive definite matrix. Which I think is OK, but I have not thought about this deeply.

```
{-3.05309*10^-15, -0.999828, -0.999979, -1.99933, -2.00264}
```

One other thing to point put is that I used `DirichletCondition` in u and not the `NeumannValue` on u. In FEM you can have the one or the other but not both at the same position. Note, however, that you could apply a different bc in v in this case, which uses an implicit Neumann zero.

Comment: I'm sorry, but the result is undesired. The Neumann b.c. chosen in this case is $\frac{\partial^3  \Psi }{\partial x^3} = 0$. And doesn't seem to be an easy way to implement OP's b.c. with `FiniteElement` of _Mathmatica_ at the moment.

Comment: @xzczd and this is what I said in my text - did I not?

Comment: Oh… sorry, I should have read the commentary more carefully.

Comment: @user21 is "pdetoae" build-in subroutine?

Comment: @ABCDEMMM user21 does suggest me to move the function to wolfram resource function repository [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/208838/solving-a-steady-state-viscous-burgers-equation-with-ndsolve/208882#comment536139_208882), but as mentioned there, the documenting of `pdetoode`/`pdetoae` is non-trivial.