# NDSolveValue and pdepe of MATLAB disagree under spherical coordinates

Tags: differential-equations, undocumented, singularity

Assuming there is a spherical activated carbon particle, the concentration outside the grain is `200` (`C[t,ri] == 200`), that inside the grain is `0` (`Derivative[0, 1][C][t, 0] == 0`), the initial condition for PDE is `C[0, r] == 0`, the radius for the particle is `ri`(`0.001` m). I am new to *Mathematica*, and when I run this code, the plot shows slight difference with that in MATLAB.

The plot in *Mathematica* sees a decline of concentration resulting a negative concentration after a period of adsorption, while it remains steady in MATLAB figure. Actually after adsorption equilibrium, the concentration should be stable . Is there a way to fix my code? Thanks.

The concentration becomes negative with growing time:

[image]

Figure in MATLAB:

[image]

The equation is like this:

[image]

*Mathematica* code:

```
TT = 3000; ri = 0.001;
sol = NDSolveValue[{D[CC[t, r], t] == 
    8*10^-10/r^2*D[r^2*D[CC[t, r], r], r] - 0.01*CC[t, r], CC[0, r] == 0, 
  CC[t, ri] == 200, Derivative[0, 1][CC][t, 0] == 0}, CC, {t, 0, TT}, {r, 0, ri, ri/50}]
Table[Plot3D[sol[t, x], {x, 0, ri}, {t, 0, VT}, PlotRange -> Full, 
  ViewPoint -> {-5, -2, 3}], {VT, 100, TT, TT/5}]
```

This is my MATLAB code:

```matlab
function test
global c0;
c0=200;         
tc=1200;
ri=0.001;

dx=70;
x=linspace(0,ri,dx); 
dtL=25;dtR=10;                  
t=[linspace(0,tc/4,dtL) linspace(tc/4+1,2000000,dtR)];
m=2;

sol=pdepe(m,@mpde,@mpic,@mpbc,x,t);
c=sol(:,:,1);
figure(1);
fig1=surf(x,t,c);
xlabel(' x');
ylabel(' t');
end
function [c,f,s]=mpde(x,t,u,du) 
c=1;
f=du*8.3E-10;
s=-0.01*u;
end
function [pl,ql,pr,qr]=mpbc(xl,ul,xr,ur,t) 
global c0;
pl=0;
ql=1;
pr=ur-c0;
qr=0;
end
function u0=mpic(x)
u0=0;
end
```

### Update 2.21:

Some results actually confused me that,

1. the stable value for `r = 0` in MATLAB is around `43`, while it is `22` in *Mathematica*.
2. a gradually increasing could be seen in initial `100` seconds, while it instantly reaches stable in *Mathematica*.

Does this discrepancy result from the difference between MATLAB and *Mathematica*  or the code itself?

```
T2 = 1000;
sol = NDSolveValue[{D[CC[r, t], t] == 
    8.3 10^-10/r^2*D[r^2*D[CC[r, t], r], r] - 0.01 CC[r, t], CC[r, 0] == 0, 
   CC[ri, t] == 200, Derivative[1, 0][CC][0, t] == 0},CC, {t, 0, T2}, {r, 0, ri, ri/50},
   Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
    "DifferentiateBoundaryConditions" -> {True, "ScaleFactor" -> 100}}]

Table[Plot3D[sol[x, t], {x, 0, ri}, {t, 0, VT2}, PlotRange -> All, 
  ColorFunction -> ColorData["BlueGreenYellow"], PlotPoints -> 100, 
  PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic, LegendMarkerSize -> {10, 200}], TicksStyle -> 13, 
  ViewPoint -> {-3, -2, 1}, AxesLabel -> {"r", "t", "z"}], {VT2, 100, T2, T2/3}]

ContourPlot[sol[r, t], {r, 0, ri}, {t, 0, T2}]
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: For reference, could you include the MATLAB code you were using (if it isn't too long)?

Comment: @J.M. I have post my Matlab code. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your solutions.

Comment: As mentioned in my last comment, you should modify the inner b.c. to `Derivative[0,1][CC][t,ri/50]==0` to avoid the removable singularity. With this b.c., the output is consistent with that of MATLAB. Also, why do you type `{r,0,ri,ri/50}`? This syntax isn't documented and colored red in the notebook. Though `NDSolve` still (surprisingly) gives a result, the mysterious syntax clearly causes certain problem.

Comment: @xzczd It is really interesting that when I change the b.c to  ```Derivative[0,1][CC][t,ri/50]==0```, and remove ```,ri/50```. The result displays that ```NDSolveValue::bcedge: Boundary condition (CC^(0,1))[t,0.00004]==0 is not specified on a single edge of the boundary of the computational domain.```

Comment: It should be `{r, ri/50, ri}`.

Comment: @xzczd Aha! A stupid mistake. Thanks for your patient answers.

Comment: Oops, `"DifferentiateBoundaryConditions" -> {True, "ScaleFactor" -> 100}}` isn't actually necessary here. The real issue turns out to be interesting. See my answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Interesting. OP has hit on an undocumented syntax of `NDSolve` that seems never be discussed in this site.

As we can see, OP has typed `{r, 0, ri, ri/50}` inside `NDSolve`. This syntax isn't mentioned in the document AFAIK, and is colored red at least in the notebook of *v8* and *v9*, but surprisingly, `NDSolve` still gives an output:

```
T2 = 1000; ri = 0.001;
inner = 0;
solaccident = 
 NDSolve[{D[CC[r, t], t] == 8.3 10^-10/r^2*D[r^2*D[CC[r, t], r], r] - 0.01 CC[r, t], 
     CC[r, 0] == 0, CC[ri, t] == 200, Derivative[1, 0][CC][inner, t] == 0}, 
    CC, {t, 0, T2}, {r, inner, ri, ri/50}][[1, 1, -1]] // Quiet
```

[image]

How does `NDSolve` interprete the `{r, 0, ri, ri/50}`? It turns out to be equivalent to `"Coordinates" -> {inner, ri, ri/50}`!:

```
solcheck = NDSolve[{D[CC[r, t], t] == 
     8.3 10^-10/r^2*D[r^2*D[CC[r, t], r], r] - 0.01 CC[r, t], CC[r, 0] == 0, 
    CC[ri, t] == 200, Derivative[1, 0][CC][inner, t] == 0}, 
   CC, {t, 0, T2}, {r, inner, ri}, 
   Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
     "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
       "Coordinates" -> {inner, ri, ri/50}}}][[1, 1, -1]]

solcheck == solaccident
(* True *)
```

Clearly, the spatial grid `{0, ri/50, ri}` is way too coarse, and results in an inaccurate result.

> Remark
>
> - The option `"Coordinates"` is documented in the tutorial [*The Numerical Method of
>   Lines*](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveMethodOfLines.html),
>   particularly *Controlling the Spatial Grid Selection* subsection.

The following is the simplest way to fix the code:

```
T2 = 1000; ri = 0.001;
inner = ri/50;
soltraditional = 
 NDSolveValue[{D[CC[r, t], t] ==8.3 10^-10/r^2*D[r^2*D[CC[r, t], r], r] - 0.01 CC[r, t],
    CC[r, 0] == 0, CC[ri, t] == 200, Derivative[1, 0][CC][inner, t] == 0}, 
  CC, {t, 0, T2}, {r, inner, ri}]
```

Though `ibcinc` warning pops up, it's not causing problem here, because the Neumann b.c. isn't the inconsistent one. (For more info check [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/123269/1871). )

I've moved the inner boundary to `ri/50` to avoid the removable singularity at origin. In principle this isn't necessary, but `NDSolve` will return the input otherwise, which may be a bug. Is it possible to circumvent the bug without moving the inner boundary? Once again, it's surprisingly possible! We just need to set the `"Coordinates"` option. Let's make use of the hidden syntax we just found:

```
T2 = 1000; ri = 0.001;
inner = 0; dr = ri/25;
soltest = NDSolveValue[{D[CC[r, t], t] == 
    8.3 10^-10/r^2*D[r^2*D[CC[r, t], r], r] - 0.01 CC[r, t], CC[r, 0] == 0, 
   CC[ri, t] == 200, Derivative[1, 0][CC][inner, t] == 0}, CC, {t, 0, T2}, 
  Flatten@{r, Range[inner, ri, dr]}]
```

`Power::infy` and `Infinity::indet` will pop up, but don't worry.

---

Further check shows this hidden syntax is introduced in *v3*:

[image]

Comment: Good find! Did not know this existed.

Comment: I failed to find the ```"Coordinates"``` option in Documentation Center, which might be the reason that I did not follow your point. Do you mean that ```"Coordinates"``` option is used to make a custom spatial grid ?

Comment: @hithere It's discussed in the tutorial [_The Numerical Method of Lines_](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveMethodOfLines.html). Yes, it's used for customizing spatial grid.