# Solving a Caputo fractional diffusion equation in cylindrical coordinates

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, heat-equation

I would like to solve this following equation with `d`, the order of the factional derivative (in the sense of Caputo) :

[image]

So I tried the following code :

```
R1 = 0.001; 
R2 = 1; 
K = 1;
d = 0.9;

eq = 1/K  CaputoD[T[t, r, θ], {t, d}] - 
   1/ (r^2)*Derivative[0, 0, 2][T][t, r, θ] - 
   1/r*Derivative[0, 1, 0][T][t, r, θ] - 
   Derivative[0, 2, 0][T][t, r, θ];

(*Initial and boundary conditions*)
ic = T[0, r, θ ] == 0;
ic1 = Derivative[1, 0, 0][T][0, r, θ] == 0;

bc = DirichletCondition[T[t, r, θ] == 1, 
   0 <= θ <= 2 Pi && r==R1];


pbc1 = PeriodicBoundaryCondition[
   T[t, r, θ], θ == 2 Pi + 0.01 && R1 < r < R2, 
   TranslationTransform[{0, -2 Pi}]];
pbc2 = PeriodicBoundaryCondition[
   T[t, r, θ], θ == -0.01 && R1 < r < R2, 
   TranslationTransform[{0, 2 Pi}]];

(*solution w/ NDSolveValue*)

sol = NDSolveValue[{eq == 0, ic, bc, pbc1, pbc2}, 
  T, {r, R1, R2}, {θ, -0.01, 2 *Pi + 0.01}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

It naturally works for `d = 1` but fails for other fractional values. A quick search for previous questions asked such as this [one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/271688/fractional-pde-with-caputod) here led me to realize that `NDSolve` cannot handle Caputo yet and that you have to rely on `DSolve` with some Laplace transforms to get solutions to such equations. A numerical solution would alternatively require a manual discretization using tools like `pdetoode`.

However, from my humble understanding of the answers presented in this post, the numerical resolution with `pdetoode` relies on a n-th order polynomial approximation and I have no idea how to adapt this to my 2D cylindrical coordinates problem. Other posts showcase different methods like the Haar wavelet method [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/271690/numerical-solution-for-a-non-linear-fractional-differential-equation-fde) but again, I can't see how to adapt this one to solving my problem.

Surprisingly, when i try to compute this equation instead :
[image]

using this modified code :

```
R1 = 0.001; 
R2 = 1; 
K = 1;
d = 0.9;

eq = 1/K  (Derivative[2, 0, 0][T][t, r, θ] + 
      CaputoD[T[t, r, θ], {t, d}]) - 
   1/ (r^2)*Derivative[0, 0, 2][T][t, r, θ] - 
   1/r*Derivative[0, 1, 0][T][t, r, θ] - 
   Derivative[0, 2, 0][T][t, r, θ];

(*Initial and boundary conditions*)
ic = T[0, r, θ ] == 0;
ic1 = Derivative[1, 0, 0][T][0, r, θ] == 0;

bc = DirichletCondition[T[t, r, θ] == 1, 
   0 <= θ <= 2 Pi && R1 <= r <= R1 + 0.001];


pbc1 = PeriodicBoundaryCondition[
   T[t, r, θ], θ == 2 Pi + 0.01 && R1 < r < R2, 
   TranslationTransform[{0, -2 Pi}]];
pbc2 = PeriodicBoundaryCondition[
   T[t, r, θ], θ == -0.01 && R1 < r < R2, 
   TranslationTransform[{0, 2 Pi}]];

(*solution w/ NDSolveValue*)

sol = NDSolveValue[{eq == 0, ic, ic1, bc, pbc1, pbc2}, 
  T, {r, R1, R2}, {θ, -0.01, 2 *Pi + 0.01}, {t, 0, 10, 1}]
```

I do get an interpolating function, which I can then visualise with

```
frames = 
  Table[DensityPlot[
    sol1[t, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], 
     Mod[ArcTan[x, y], 2 Pi]], {x, y} ∈ reg2D, 
    Axes -> {True, True, False}, AxesLabel -> {x, y}, 
    PlotRange -> All, AxesStyle -> Directive[Purple, 12], 
    ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", ColorFunctionScaling  -> False, 
    PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {0, 1}}], 
    PlotLabel -> Row[{"t=", t}]], {t, 0, 10, 1}];

Export["test.mp4", frames]
```

So here are my two questions :

1 - How can I solve numerically the first equation (without the 2nd order derivative wrt time)

2 - I have read that `NDSolve` cannot handle Caputo but if I add a second order derivative w.r.t. time, it solves the equation. I'd like to know if the solution I get truly is the solution to my second equation or if `NDSolve` somehow disregards Caputo to compute the whole thing. The reason why I ask this is I have tested several values of fractional order `d` and there doesn't seem to be much change, hence the question.

I apologize for the long post. I am more interested in solving the first equation but if you have any idea about my second question, I would also appreciate your insight on the matter.

Have a great day.

Comment: 1. What b.c. are you trying to set at `r==R1`? (The definition of `bc` looks a bit suspicious. ) 2. You're aware that zero Nemann condition will be set at `r==R2`, right? 3. In this toy sample the solution is actually axisymmetric, is the $θ$ dependence necessary for you in real case? 4. You wrote `{t, 0, 10, 1}`, do you really know what it means?: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/240406/1871

Comment: 5. As to 2nd question, your guess is right, `NDSolve` doesn't parse the `CaputoD` correctly, just add a meaningless coefficient to the `CaputoD` term and try, or use [``NDSolve`FEM`GetInactivePDE``](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/225841/1871). A much simpler example showing the issue: `NDSolveValue[{y'[x] + aaadvddd CaputoD[y[x], {x, 0.5}] == Sin[x], y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 30}]`

Comment: @xzczd  1- I guess I was going for a "hot inner wall" type of bc, if we are reasoning with heat transfer.  I guess a `````bc = DirichletCondition[T[t, r, \[Theta]] == 1, 
  0 <= \[Theta] <= 2 Pi && r == R1];```` would have been enough.

Comment: @xzczd
2- I was not aware of this. But coincidentally, I was working previously with an additional boundary condition ````cb = NeumannValue[0, r == R1] + NeumannValue[0, r == R2]```` which I ended up removing since whether it was there or not it was there didn't seem to change the solution. I guess I now know why.

3 - I do have a Theta dependence in my real case.
4- I wasn't aware of this either and made this mistake probably because of my habits in python. I'll correct this right now.
5 - Thanks for confirming it. I now know that results for my second equation are not reliable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, let me extend the useful part of my comments: as to 2nd question, your guess is right. `NDSolve` doesn't parse the `CaputoD` correctly in 2nd sample. A simpler example showing the issue:

```
{NDSolveValue[{y'[x] + aaadvddd CaputoD[y[x], {x, 0.5}] == Sin[x], y[0] == 1}, 
              y, {x, 0, 2 Pi}], 
 NDSolveValue[{y'[x] == Sin[x], y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 2 Pi}]} // 
 ListPlot[#, PlotMarkers -> {o, x}] &
```

[image]

As we can see, the meaningless term `aaadvddd CaputoD[y[x], {x, 0.5}]` is ignored silently.

Then let's deal with 1st question. The solution in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/271689/1871) can be extended to 2D in a staightforward manner. As usual, I'll use [`pdetoode`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127997/1871) for spatial discretization:

```
tend = 1/40;
R1 = 1/1000;
R2 = 1;
d = 9/10;
With[{T = T[t, r, θ]},
 eq = CaputoD[T, {t, d}] - D[T, {θ, 2}]/r^2 - D[T, r]/r - D[T, {r, 2}] == 0;
 ic = T == 0 /. t -> 0;
 bc = {T == 1 /. r -> R1, D[T, r] == 0 /. r -> R2};]
 
{points@t, points@r, points@θ} = {15, 25, 25};    
{domain@t, domain@r, domain@θ} = {{0, tend}, {R1, R2}, {-Pi, Pi}};

CGLGrid[xl_, xr_, n_Integer /; n > 1] := 
 1/2 (xl + xr + (xl - xr) Cos[(π Range[0, n - 1])/(n - 1)])
grid@t = CGLGrid[##, points@t] & @@ domain@t;
(grid@# = Array[# &, points@#, domain@#]) & /@ {r, θ};

difforder = 2;
(* Definition of pdetoode isn't included in this post,
   please find it in the link above. *)
ptoofunc = pdetoode[T[t, r, θ], t, grid /@ {r, θ}, difforder, {False, True}];

del = #[[2 ;; -2]] &;
SetAttributes[ca, Listable]    
ode = del@ptoofunc[eq /. CaputoD[a_, b_] :> ca[a]]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.357973, Null} *)
odeic = del@ptoofunc@ic; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.0016925, Null} *)    
odebc = ptoofunc@bc; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.0028338, Null} *)
```

> **Remark**
>
> 1. `ca` with `Listable` attribute is introduced to temporarily replace `CaputoD` because the new-introduced `CaputoD` is incredibly slow on expression that actually doesn't need
>    to be calculated. Minimal example: `Clear[f, t]; Table[CaputoD[f[i, j][t], {t, 1/2}], {i, 5}, {j, 5}]; // AbsoluteTiming`.
> 2. The periodic b.c. in $\theta$ direction is set by 5th argument of `pdetoode`. Here `{False, True}` means 1st dimension i.e. $r$
>    direction is not periodic but 2nd dimension i.e. $\theta$ direction is
>    periodic.

Then we use n-th order polynomial whose coefficient is determined by function values at Chebyshev-Gauss-Lobatto grid to approximate solution in $t$ direction. An `InterpolatingFunction` is generated as the output for convenience:

```
range = Range[0, points@t - 1];
coef[x_, y_] = c[x, y] /@ range;
poly[x_, y_][t_] = coef[x, y] . t^range;

{approxode, approxic, approxbc} = {ode, odeic, odebc} /. T -> poly /. 
    ca[a_] :> CaputoD[a, {t, d}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {2.11858, Null} *)

var = Outer[coef, grid@r, grid@θ] // Flatten;
sys = Flatten@{Table[approxode, {t, Rest@#}], Table[approxbc, {t, #}], approxic} &@
    grid@t; // AbsoluteTiming
{barray, marray} = CoefficientArrays[sys, var]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {6.03323, Null} *)
(* {6.30408, Null} *)

csol = LinearSolve[marray, -N[barray]]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {1.87547, Null} *)

nsol = Block[{c}, Evaluate@var = csol;
    ListInterpolation[
     Table[poly[x, y][t], {t, grid@t}, {x, grid@r}, {y, grid@θ}], 
     grid /@ {t, r, θ}]]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.633282, Null} *)
```

Finally, visualization. I use `ToElementMesh` to discretize the region first to speed up `Plot3D`:

```
<< NDSolve`FEM`

reg = 
  ToElementMesh[ImplicitRegion[R1^2 < x^2 + y^2 < R2^2, {x, y}], 
   MaxCellMeasure -> Pi R2^2/(4 10^3)];

lst = 
   Table[Plot3D[nsol[t, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], ArcTan[x, y]], {x, y} ∈ reg, 
     Exclusions -> None, PlotRange -> {-1, 1}], {t, 0, tend, 
     tend/points@t}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {8.53243, Null} *)

lst // ListAnimate
```

[image]

Oops, I forgot `RevolutionPlot3D` is a better choice in this case:

```
lst = 
   Table[RevolutionPlot3D[nsol[t, r, θ], {r, R1, R2}, {θ, -Pi, Pi}, 
     PlotRange -> {-1, 1}], {t, 0, tend, tend/points@t}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {1.87516, Null} *)
    
lst // ListAnimate
```

[image]

As we can see, the solution reaches equilibrium quite fast, that's the reason I modify `tend` to `1/40`.

Comment: I thank you for this answer. By the way, when I used your code, I ended up with 3 error messages along the line of 
```` InterpolatingFunction::dmval: Input value {0,1.41401,-2.35619} lies outside the range of data in the interpolating function. Extrapolation will be used.```` 
as well as 
````General::stop: Further output of InterpolatingFunction::dmval will be suppressed during this calculation.````

I imagine the 1st error has to do with points in the plotrange not being in the interpolation domain, but what about the second error. Do you perhaps know the reason for it ?

Comment: @ConfuzzledStudent Which version and OS are you in? I can't reproduce it on Wolfram Cloud, but the version number therein is `"13.2.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (November 2, 2022)"`(!). If I have to guess, this is a bug that's fixed in version 13.2, changing `nsol[t, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], ArcTan[x, y]]` to `If[R1^2 < x^2 + y^2 < R2^2, nsol[t, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], ArcTan[x, y]], 0.]` should fix the problem in your version.

Comment: I am on the 13.1 version on windows 10. Implementing the changes you suggested did remove the errors, but now the peak from the Plot3D looks like [this](https://i.imgur.com/IFSmH0W.png).

Well I guess this is just a minor issue so in the end, thank you for the enlightening answer.

Comment: @ConfuzzledStudent Does e.g. adding `PlotPoints->100` to `Plot3D` help?

Comment: It definitely helped alright. Thanks.

Comment: @ConfuzzledStudent Oops, I forgot `RevolutionPlot3D`, see the update.

Comment: So i was under the impression that increasing ````{points@t, points@r, points@θ} = {15, 25, 25};  ```` would result in more accurate results but it appears that some very exotic stuff happens when you just increase ````points@t```` to 20 or 25. It's very noticeable when you increase ````tend````.  For instance, tend at 1 and points@t = 25, you get [this](https://imgur.com/zkAp7HJ).
Do you have an idea of what is going on there ?

Comment: @ConfuzzledStudent My laptop doesn't have enough RAM so cannot test, but try modifying `-N[barray]` to e.g. `-N[barray, 32]`.

Comment: So i tried implementing this change and what happened was that the program ran for 10 hours while taking about 10 gb of ram and unfortunately, I think i ran out of memory or something because all the variables returned to being blue while no outputs were produced. How unfortunate.

Comment: @ConfuzzledStudent Not too surprsing, my method for solving FDE is primary. The missing of a built-in numeric FDE solver at the moment is a pain. Anyway, as a last struggle, you may try adjusting `Method` option of `LinearSolve`, because the crash might be caused by improper method choosing of it.

Comment: I tried several methods on in ````LinearSolve```` as you advised me such as ````Method -> "Multifrontal"```` and ````Method -> "Krylov"```` but these gave an error output fast. Other methods such as ````Method -> "Cholesky"```` doesn't really fix the issue as the program runs for a very long time (more than a day) and will probably crash just as before (i had to abort in the end). I haven't tried the last two methods yet (````"DivisionFreeRowReduction"```` and ````"CofactorExpansion"````) but i don't really have high hopes.

Comment: After many hours of run time, none of the methods in ````Method```` worked for me. I guess, it would appear that these singularities might be due to Caputo as when i put `````d=1````, no weird stuff happens.
@xzczd

It might also be due to Gibbs phenomena but that's unlikely.... I really hope these are just numerical irregularities.