# Chladni experiment verification

Tags: differential-equations, physics, eigenvalues, frequency

### I refurbished my post in order to be more understandable.

After computing simulations of Chladni patterns with Mathematica (see my previous topics), I finally went to practice. I realized my own experience. So, I have compared my results with the theory. And the obtained patterns are not really matching the expected ones.
My hypothesis is that the boundary conditions I used in Mathematica are not the good ones. I think *all simply-supported edges* bc must be replaced by *all fully free edges* bc, because, in original Chladni experiment, the plate is “clamped” in the middle and excited from an edge. So, all edges are free. And it is more true with modern variant, because the plate is excited from the center with a Melde Vibrator, and the plate is no more clamped.

So my first question is: *how to introduce the **fully free edges** boundary condition within the eigenvalues equation: Dirichlet? Neumann?* I am a little bit lost.

My second question is: *what is the formula to get f(m,n,a,b)* - f=natural frequency - *for a **fully free ends plate** (m and n are the mode coeff. and [a,b] the plate dimensions)?*

You will find hereafter my code to illustrate all my questions:

```
(* My code to illustrate my questions *)
a = 0.18;
b = 0.18; h = 0.001;(*length,witdh,thickness in m*)
Ey = 2.1 10^11;(*N/m^2*)(*Young modulus*)
\[Rho] = 7800;(*kg/m^2*)(*density*)
\[Nu] = 0.3;(*Poisson coeff.*)
Df = (Ey h^3)/(12 (1 - \[Nu]^2))(*flexural rigidity*)
d = Sqrt[Df/(\[Rho] h)] (*coeff.correponding to the plate's \
mechanical behavior to introduce within Double Laplacian equations*)

eqnr = {-(d) Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] + 
    v[x, y], -(d) Laplacian[
     v[x, y], {x, y}]};(*bi-harmonic eigenvalue system*)
(*bi-harmonic eigenvalue system*)
bcsr = DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, True];
(*BC used with SS plate/what is the equivalent for Fully Free Edges \
plate?*)

{valr, funr} = 
   NDEigensystem[{eqnr, bcsr}, {u, v}, {x, 0, a}, {y, 0, b}, 
    80]; // Quiet

f = valr/(2 \[Pi]) (*to get all modal frequencies and functions*)

Table[ContourPlot[Re[funr[[i, 1]][x, y]] == 0, {x, 0, a}, {y, 0, b}, 
  PlotRange -> All, PlotLabel -> Re[valr[[i]]/(2 Pi)] "Hz", 
  AspectRatio -> Automatic, ImageSize -> Tiny, 
  FrameTicks -> None], {i, 1, Length[valr]}]
(*to get the nodal lines patterns which should match the results of \
my experiment-see photos below*)

(*below is the formula to get natural freqencies for a simply-supported plate*)
fss[m_, n_] := \[Pi]/2 Sqrt[
   Df/(\[Rho] h)] (m^2/a^2 + n^2/b^2);(*Hz*)TMss = 
 Table[fss[m, n], {m, 1, 9}, {n, 1, 9}];
(* Natural frequencies table (in Hz) computed with the well-known \
formula: *)
TableForm[TMss, 
 TableHeadings -> {{"m1", "m2", "m3", "m4", "m5", "m6", "m7", "m8", 
    "m9"}, {"n1", "n2", "n3", "n4", "n5", "n6", "n7", "n8", "n9"}}]

(*what is the equivalent formula for a fully free edges plate?*)

(* Animation of the plates vibrations: *)
ListAnimate[
 Table[Plot3D[Re[funr[[i, 1]][x, y]], {x, 0, a}, {y, 0, b}, 
   PlotRange -> All, PlotLabel -> Re[valr[[i]]/(2 Pi)] "Hz", 
   ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", AspectRatio -> Automatic], {i, 1, 
   Length[valr]}], AnimationRepetitions -> 1, DefaultDuration -> 20]
```

You will see the frequency values are not matching the values computed with my Mathematica code. Thank you in advance for your answers. You will find hereafter the diagram showing the details of the assembly.

---

In order to clarify this topic, you will find additional elements :

1/ The formula to compute the natural frequencies (or pulsations) I have found in the litterature is the following one :

```
fss[m_, n_] := \[Pi]/2 Sqrt[Df/(\[Rho] h)] (m^2/a^2 + n^2/b^2)
```

The table computed with the formula

[image: F table]
There are frequency discrepencies between the table and the patterns computed with MMA code (see below).

This table applies for a Simply Supported plate.
What is the good one for Fully free edges plate?

2/ The BC I used is the following one, but I think it s not correct for my purpose :

```
bcsr = DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, True]
```

3/ Some pictures to improve the understanding

Under the Monacor exciter:
[image: under Monacor]

And the correponding assembly diagram:
[image: Plate assembly]

The nodal patterns computed with the MMA code (there a lot of "intermediate" modes):
[image: Nodal patterns]

My own patterns (not all, because the big difficulty I met was to get a very accurate tuning, according the fact my wife was getting angry because of the high-pitched whistling generated by the devices):

[image: My experiment]

Comment: Thinking about this, I come to the conclusion that at a free edge, there is no curvature perpendicular to the edge. That would mean the second derivative perpendicular to the edge is zero. Does anybody have a proof of this?  In 1D the standard way is to calculate the general solution and then chose the parameters so the the amplitude at the ends is maximal. But I see another problem, if you excite the plate at the middle, this is different to Chladni who fixes the plate at the middle.

Comment: Hi, the parameters of my experiment are the following ones :
- a steel square plate "dedicated" to this purpose (3B Scientific U56006),
- a Monacor AR-30 as a vibrator, driven by a small Audio power amp and anchored to the plate in the middle,
- a sinus wave generator connected to the power amp.

Of course, I am not sure about the plate's parameters (E, nu, rau), so I took "common average values" for these parameters.

Comment: @Pascal77 What is the length and thickness of the plate you are experimenting with?

Comment: @Alex The length and width are 18cm.
The thickness is 1  mm.
In fact, all parameters are inside my here joined MMA code :)

Comment: @Pascal77 Hence your code is dedicated to simulate real plate vibration? How the plate is clamped in the middle (size of clamped area)?

Comment: @Alex I hope my code is correct for this purpose, it is inspired from our last exchange :). 
I used the bi-harmonic eigenvalue problem equation (divided into 2 second order equations with the coeff. I called d in my code which takes into account the mechanical features.
Having said that, the thing I am sure is that boundary conditions are not OK and the formula defining the natural pulsation is not the good one.

Comment: @Alex The "clamped" area is around 3 cm diameter, but standing on 3 points only, not on a disk  or a coronna. I adopted this method because I can't screw the plate to the exciter in the center.

Comment: @Alex Nevertheless I bought a Melde vibrator which will allow me to screw directly the plate to the vibrator axis with a 5mm hole in the middle. I am still waiting for the vibrator I ordered  on the web.

Comment: @Pascal77 How these 3 point located on the plate?

Comment: @Alex these 3 points are located all around the plate center hole. The virtual circle formed by the 3 points is centered around the middle of the plate.

Comment: Maybe useful: [Chladni Figures](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ChladniFigures). Please do NOT post additional info as answers. Instead - edit your original post and add your information there. Move your comments that are not answers to your original post. Make sure you have seen the [TOUR](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)

Comment: @Vitaliy: OK. From now on, I will do that. Sorry for my mistake.

Comment: I tried to compute my problem if the plate is simply-supported on the 3 points depicted above in blue. So the boundary conditions should be u(x,y)=0 for P1 & P2 & P3, where P1, P2 and P3 are the 3 points. All other points of the plate are free to move according the vibrations produced by the vibrator. Am I right? 
So, how to write these boundary conditions on 3 points? I tried with 3 dedicated Dirichlet conditions but MMA gives me back two error messages. I tried also u[P1x, P1y] == 0, u[P2x, P2y] == 0, 
u[P3x, P3y] == 0 but it doesn't work.
P1=0.09, 0.1, 
P2=0.082, 0.085,
P3=0.099, 0.085

Comment: Just for information, I found this interesting article concerning my questions. Unfortunately, the author uses finite volume method (which I don't know) to simulate the Chladni experiment. 

https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s42452-020-04062-6.pdf

Comment: 1. What's the corresponding b.c. for the formula `fss[m_, n_] := \[Pi]/2 Sqrt[Df/(\[Rho] h)] (m^2/a^2 + n^2/b^2)`? Can you add a link to the literature? 2. Have you read this?: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/149488/1871

Comment: @ xzczd : yes, I read the topic you remind above. The bi-harmonic equation is solved with two laplacians. I also tried this method. My problem in this case, is how to apply correctly Dirichlet and/or Neumann Values BC. 
So personnally, I prefer using the entire bi-harmonic equation, but I know we are on the fringe with Mathematica.
Regarding the literature,

Comment: the literature : see https://www.intechopen.com/books/advanced-engineering-testing/effect-of-various-edge-conditions-on-free-vibration-characteristics-of-isotropic-square-and-rectangu

Comment: another ref. : Vibration of Plates by Snehashish Chakraverty (see Chapter 4 p46)
There are a lot of books or articles dealing with this subject.